# Laravel backpack Permission Explain with User Association / Relationship

Tags: laravel-backpack

#### How to Access Data / Field just One User

I was create crud data with Laravel backpack And confuse about limited access data for just one people with delegation. I try using Request file

```
public function authorize()
{
    // only allow updates if the user is logged in
    return \Auth::check()->user_id;
}
```

but nothing. still have access for other and some user.

I use this project like Task Manager.

User A : Manager (Role)
User B : Client (Role)
User C : Client (Role)

**User A** Create File / Data / Upload Doc (sample.txt) for **User B** and User B Just See thats.

***User C*** : Can Access that index methode and see none file and can't see sample.txt (Owned by **User B**)

What i have to do?

Comment: The ```Request``` file only handles the validation. It's a good thing to check the user has permission there, but you need to also do it inside your ```EntityCrudController```.

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may put your check inside the ```setup()``` method (which would prevent ALL actions), or inside each method that you need restricted (ex: ```search()``` for listing entries, ```create()``` for creation, ```update()``` for editing, etc).